# Bijection Function composition

Tags: elementary-set-theory

if $f\colon A\to A$ is Bijection is that means that $f^n\circ f = f  \circ f^n $ ?

Comment: That's true also if $\;f\;$ isn't a bijection...as long as the composition is well defined.

Comment: That holds for any map $f\colon A\to A$.

Answer (score 0):

A *bijective* function $f\colon X\to Y$ is one that is *injective* and *surjective*, that is for every $y\in Y$ there is exactly one $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$ (surjectivity guarentees that there is at least one such $x$, while injectivity ensures that this $x$ is unique).

On the other hand, the composition of $f\colon X\to Y$ and $g\colon Y\to Z$ is defined whenever ${\rm codom}~f\subseteq{\rm dom}~g$. So if $f\colon A\to A$, the certainly ${\rm codom}~f\subseteq{\rm dom}~f$ as ${\rm dom}~f=A$ for $f$ to be a function (at least according to common conventions; see [partial function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function) and [total function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function#Total_function)). Of course, in case of $f$ being a bijection this holds trivially aswell.

In both cases, iterating $f$ is well-defined and can be defined recursively by $f^1=f$ and $f^{n+1}=f\circ f^n$ for $n\ge1$. Your rule can be proven by induction on $n$. Certainly it holds for $n=1$. But as function composition is associative we have
$$f\circ f^n=f\circ(f\circ f^{n-1})=f\circ(f^{n-1}\circ f)=(f\circ f^{n-1})\circ f=f^n\circ f$$
Intuitively, this has to hold as we apply $f$ exactly $n+1$-times in both cases. Under the surface associativity makes sure that our intuition holds true.